# Drawing tikz arcs (crt drawing)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a CRT (cathode ray tube) similar to the example in the picture below.

[image]

I did a good part, being the texts i will put in a presentation and not in the drawing itself. I'm using the TikzEdt app. I can't reduce the size of the bow, so the figure is very strange. Could someone help me reduce the size of the front and back bows of the drawing? make them less curved?

my tikz code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Ajusta o tamanho dos bipolos R, L, C
    \ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=.5}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=.2}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/width=.4}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/height=.2}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width=.2}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=.3}

    \draw
        %-- Filamento de aquecimento
        (0.25, 0.00) to [short] (1.00, 0.00)
        (1.00, 1.00) to [L] (1.00, 0.00)
        (0.25, 1.00) to [short] (1.00, 1.00)

        %-- Catodo
        (0.00, -0.25) to [short] (1.25, -0.25)
        (1.25, -0.25) to [short] (1.25, 1.25)
        (1.25, 1.25) to [short] (1.00, 1.25)
    ;
    %-- Grade de controle
    \draw [dashed] (1.50, -0.50) -- (1.50, 1.50);

    %-- Sistema de focalização
    \node at (2.50, 0.50) [cylinder, draw=black, thick, aspect=1.00, minimum height=1.50cm, minimum width=0.75cm, shape border rotate=0, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=gray!10, cylinder end fill=gray!5] {};

    %-- Placas de deflexão vertical
    \draw (4.00, 0.00) -- (5.00, 0.00);
    \draw (4.25, 0.25) -- (5.25, 0.25);
    \draw (4.00, 0.00) -- (4.25, 0.25);
    \draw (5.00, 0.00) -- (5.25, 0.25);
    \draw (4.00, 0.75) -- (5.00, 0.75);
    \draw (4.25, 1.00) -- (5.25, 1.00);
    \draw (4.00, 0.75) -- (4.25, 1.00);
    \draw (5.00, 0.75) -- (5.25, 1.00);

    %-- Placas de deflexão horizontal
    \draw (6.00, 0.10) -- (6.00, 0.60);
    \draw (7.00, 0.10) -- (7.00, 0.60);
    \draw (6.00, 0.10) -- (7.00, 0.10);
    \draw (6.00, 0.60) -- (7.00, 0.60);
    \draw (6.50, 0.95) -- (7.50, 0.95);
    \draw (6.50, 0.95) -- (6.50, 0.60);
    \draw (7.50, 0.95) -- (7.50, 0.45);
    \draw (7.50, 0.45) -- (7.00, 0.45);

    %-- Corpo do CRT
    \draw (0.00, -0.50) -- (8.00, -0.50);
    \draw (0.00, 1.50) -- (8.00, 1.50);

    %-- Traseira do tubo
    \draw (0.00, 1.50) arc (90:270:1) ;

    %-- Frente do tubo
    \draw (8.00, 1.50) -- (14.00, 5.00);
    \draw (8.00, -0.50) -- (14.00, -4.00);
    \draw (14.00, 5.00) arc (90:-90:4.5) ;

    %-- Feixe de elétrons
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.10)  -- (1.50, 0.10);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.20)  -- (1.50, 0.20);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.30)  -- (1.50, 0.30);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.40)  -- (1.50, 0.40);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.50)  -- (1.50, 0.50);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.60)  -- (1.50, 0.60);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.70)  -- (1.50, 0.70);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.80)  -- (1.50, 0.80);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.90)  -- (1.50, 0.90);

    %-- Feixe de elétrons 2
    \draw [dotted, thin] (1.50, 0.55)  -- (1.85, 0.55);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (3.25, 0.55)  -- (6.00, 0.55);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (7.00, 0.55)  -- (9.00, 0.55);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (1.50, 0.50)  -- (1.85, 0.50);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (3.25, 0.50)  -- (6.00, 0.50);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (7.00, 0.50)  -- (9.00, 0.50);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (1.50, 0.45)  -- (1.85, 0.45);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (3.25, 0.45)  -- (6.00, 0.45);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (7.00, 0.45)  -- (9.00, 0.45);

    %-- Legendas dos elementos
    %\node (A) at (-0.70, 2.00) {\scriptsize $u\left(t\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the back with e.g.

```
\draw (0.00, 1.50) to[bend right=40] (0,-0.5);
```

and the front with

```
\draw (8.00, 1.50) -- (14.00, 5.00) to[bend left=20] (14.00, -4.00) -- (8.00, -0.50);
```

Adjust the values for `bend left`/`right` to your liking, they represent the `bend angle`.

On second thought, I'd do the whole outside border in one path:

```
\draw (0.00, 1.50) to[bend right=40]
      (0,-0.5) -- (8.00, -0.50) --
      (14.00, -4.00) to[bend right=20]
      (14.00, 5.00) -- (8.00, 1.50) -- cycle;
```

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Ajusta o tamanho dos bipolos R, L, C
    \ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=.5}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=.2}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/width=.4}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/height=.2}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width=.2}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=.3}

    \draw
        %-- Filamento de aquecimento
        (0.25, 0.00) to [short] (1.00, 0.00)
        (1.00, 1.00) to [L] (1.00, 0.00)
        (0.25, 1.00) to [short] (1.00, 1.00)

        %-- Catodo
        (0.00, -0.25) to [short] (1.25, -0.25)
        (1.25, -0.25) to [short] (1.25, 1.25)
        (1.25, 1.25) to [short] (1.00, 1.25)
    ;
    %-- Grade de controle
    \draw [dashed] (1.50, -0.50) -- (1.50, 1.50);

    %-- Sistema de focalização
    \node at (2.50, 0.50) [cylinder, draw=black, thick, aspect=1.00, minimum height=1.50cm, minimum width=0.75cm, shape border rotate=0, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=gray!10, cylinder end fill=gray!5] {};

    %-- Placas de deflexão vertical
    \draw (4.00, 0.00) -- (5.00, 0.00);
    \draw (4.25, 0.25) -- (5.25, 0.25);
    \draw (4.00, 0.00) -- (4.25, 0.25);
    \draw (5.00, 0.00) -- (5.25, 0.25);
    \draw (4.00, 0.75) -- (5.00, 0.75);
    \draw (4.25, 1.00) -- (5.25, 1.00);
    \draw (4.00, 0.75) -- (4.25, 1.00);
    \draw (5.00, 0.75) -- (5.25, 1.00);

    %-- Placas de deflexão horizontal
    \draw (6.00, 0.10) -- (6.00, 0.60);
    \draw (7.00, 0.10) -- (7.00, 0.60);
    \draw (6.00, 0.10) -- (7.00, 0.10);
    \draw (6.00, 0.60) -- (7.00, 0.60);
    \draw (6.50, 0.95) -- (7.50, 0.95);
    \draw (6.50, 0.95) -- (6.50, 0.60);
    \draw (7.50, 0.95) -- (7.50, 0.45);
    \draw (7.50, 0.45) -- (7.00, 0.45);

    %-- Corpo do CRT
    \draw (0.00, -0.50) -- (8.00, -0.50);
    \draw (0.00, 1.50) -- (8.00, 1.50);

    %-- Traseira do tubo
    \draw (0.00, 1.50) to[bend right=40] (0,-0.5);

    %-- Frente do tubo
    \draw (8.00, 1.50) -- (14.00, 5.00) to[bend left=20] (14.00, -4.00) -- (8.00, -0.50);

    %-- Feixe de elétrons
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.10)  -- (1.50, 0.10);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.20)  -- (1.50, 0.20);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.30)  -- (1.50, 0.30);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.40)  -- (1.50, 0.40);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.50)  -- (1.50, 0.50);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.60)  -- (1.50, 0.60);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.70)  -- (1.50, 0.70);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.80)  -- (1.50, 0.80);
    \draw [dotted] (1.25, 0.90)  -- (1.50, 0.90);

    %-- Feixe de elétrons 2
    \draw [dotted, thin] (1.50, 0.55)  -- (1.85, 0.55);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (3.25, 0.55)  -- (6.00, 0.55);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (7.00, 0.55)  -- (9.00, 0.55);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (1.50, 0.50)  -- (1.85, 0.50);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (3.25, 0.50)  -- (6.00, 0.50);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (7.00, 0.50)  -- (9.00, 0.50);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (1.50, 0.45)  -- (1.85, 0.45);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (3.25, 0.45)  -- (6.00, 0.45);
    \draw [dotted, thin] (7.00, 0.45)  -- (9.00, 0.45);

    %-- Legendas dos elementos
    %\node (A) at (-0.70, 2.00) {\scriptsize $u\left(t\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very good. i was having a hard time figuring out how to make it look like this. thanks for your help.